# Don't animate a property in transitionWithView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewanimation

I'm currently flipping a UIImageView using `UIView transitionWithView: duration: options: animations: completion:` and switching the image inside the animation block. One of the two images it's switching between is landscape and the other is portrait so its also rotating and resizing the imageview so they both fill the screen.

What I can't figure out is how to animate the flip, and rotate it at the appropriate time but not animate the rotation. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In case anyone is curious, I ended up just rotating the image before I saved/loaded it therefore removing the need to put a rotation or resize in the animation block.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try putting the change you don't want to be animated inside a CATransaction begin/commit, with setDisableActions:TRUE. (inside your animation block.) I don't know if it would work or not, but it would be worth a try.